# Get the value of the column of which the Serial no is greatest

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table(table_name), the columns of which are Sno,count.
If wanna get the value of the count column where Sno is, say 1..

```
SELECT count FROM `table_name` WHERE Sno=1;
```

gives

```
count
 2
```

it works!!!

But what if I wanna get the value of count where Sno is Max?

```
Sno  count
 1    2
 2    1
```

Basically I need help creating hybrid of :

```
SELECT count FROM `table_name` WHERE Sno=1;
```

&

```
select MAX(Sno) from table_name;
```

Comment: Use subquery. 
SELECT count FROM `table_name` WHERE Sno = (select MAX(Sno) from table_name);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM `table_name` t
ORDER BY Sno DESC
LIMIT 1;
```